# How to run dependant tasks even after independent tasks failing?

Tags: dependency-management, azure-webjobs

I want to know if there is a way to run dependant task even if the other tasks have failed. I had found a way to do it using:

```
Default = new ExitOptions 
{ 
    DependencyAction = DependencyAction.Satisfy 
}
```

The problem arose when the class ExitOptions did not have the property in Azure Batch dll version 5.0.0.0. Could someone suggest an alternative or the version which has the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem arose when the class ExitOptions did not have the property in Azure Batch dll version 5.0.0.0.

You could try to update the version of `Azure.Batch` to **greater than or equal to 6.0.0.0**. Then yo could get the `DependencyAction` property you want.

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: If it solved you problem, you could accept it as an answer to close your question.